# How to highlight the object which VR hand will grab in Unity VR

Tags: unity-game-engine, highlight, virtual-reality

I have many screws on my table but I want to highlight the screw which will be grabbed by my hand.

I have used screw's hover to highlight but every screw in my hand's sphere collider will highlight.
and I try to add bool to avoid above question ,however, it will highlight one screw but it won't be my hand's grabbed object ,because if I move my hand the sensor will change to another screw which didn't be highlighted.

Comment: Try looping through all screws in the sphere collider and only highlight the one closest to the center (or whichever metric is used to select which screw is picked up).